# Google Maps latitude and longitude search without markers

Tags: search, google-maps

When I search a latitude and longitude in Google Maps like:

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=-25.454435,-49.33136
```

It always return me the locations nearby with those ["A", "B", ... ] pins:

[image]

Is there any way of getting only the green pointer created by the `q` parameter and hide everything else (using some other URL parameter, perhaps) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `loc:` in front of the coordinate, like this -

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:-25.454435,-49.33136
```

Here's what you get -

[image]

When you don't use `loc:`, Google shows the nearest possible place for the convenience of the user as it's a random point. But when you're using `loc:` Google knows that you are looking for just the location of the point, nothing else.

**Update:**

If you want to show a info bubble on that certain coordinate, you can also do it this way -

```
https://maps.google.com/maps?q=LocationName@-25.454435,-49.33136&iwloc=A
```

Here it'll point to that certain location with a red marker `A` and you can set information about it inside a info window + with `iwloc`, you can say that it needs to show the info to the red bubble marked `A`. Output -

[image]

Comment: Cool! As it's a baloon marker, can I add the description for this `loc` thing in the URL?

Comment: @ViniciusMassuchetto yes you can. Updated the answer. :)

Comment: Thanks! Awesome! Just wondering again if I can now add multiple balloons using only the URL.

Comment: Search for a string that has multiple matching location? :P

Comment: Yeah, sort of. I want to put multiple markers with balloons in the map.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the new google maps :S

Comment: Of course not. Google has completely changed their maps. I try to revise the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you search your location using http://www.hamstermap.com/quickmap.php you will get the location back without any marker displayed. 
The primary function of the website is to put multiple markers on the map, however the location search works exactly the way you need it :)